# Sorting a US formatted column in html-table

Tags: reactjs, sorting, html-table

I am using html-table to show data. There is a column named `Charges` in my table, which shows currency in US format. The data is coming from the array collection `patientsSearchData`. (I want to sort Charges ascending and descending while clicking an icon )

Sample column format

[image]

```
 new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USD', { currency: 'USD', style: 'currency' }).format(Number(Item.Charges))
```

The above code is used for USD format.

Charges are coming from array in string format

Eg:

> var charges =["1,416.20", "807.21", "42.82", "187.17"]

The sort I applied is:

```
sort(event) {
        const {patientsSearchData } = this.state;
        const { SearchList } = this.props;
        var search = [];
        if (SearchList.length == 0) {
                search = _.orderBy(patientsSearchData, (o) => typeof o[event.target.id] === 'string' ? o[event.target.id].trim().toLowerCase() : o[event.target.id], order[event.target.id] ? 'asc' : 'desc');
                this.setState({
                orderby: event.target.id,
                patientsSearchData: search,
            });
        }
```

After sorting (in ascending order), and applying USD format, what it looks like in the html-table is shown below:

> $1,416.20
>
> $187.17
>
> $42.82
>
> $807.21

What actually I need is:

> $42.82
>
> $187.17
>
> $807.21
>
> $1,416.20

Comment: Is it possible to sort before you format? Then you can just `arr.map(Number).sort((a,b)=>(a-b)*direction)` where direction is 1 for ascending and -1 for descending.

Comment: My array collection contains other fields such as Name, Address etc , which are string fields . So is it possible to sort the entire html-table using `arr.map(Number).sort((a,b)=>(a-b)*direction)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I did one more checking in the `sort` function that if the value in array contains only number or decimal points.

```
else if (event.target.id === 'Charges'){
                search = _.orderBy(patientsSearchData, (o) => o[event.target.id].match(/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/) ? Math.floor(o[event.target.id]) : o[event.target.id], order[event.target.id] ? 'asc' : 'desc');
            }
```